# Extension method error

Tags: c#

Just got this error message **"Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"**, following is the Class that gives me the error, and I know it has got something to do with the Fisher-Yates shuffle method, but even if I remove it, the error still appears. I also remove every other call of that method, so I can only assume its some auto-generated file that is the problem.. Any idea what I can do? Cause my program ran just fine before I implemented that shuffle.

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
    {
        class RandomContent
        {
            public static string randomFilepath()
        {
            // string array med alla filpaths
            // välj en slumpad filpath att returnera
            return "frågor.txt";
        }

        // Fisher-Yates list-shuffle
        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
        {
            Random rng = new Random();
            int n = list.Count;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                T value = list[k];
                list[k] = list[n];
                list[n] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the message?

Comment: "non-generic static class"... I do not see your class as static, why blame Fisher-Yates or auto generated code.

Comment: On a side note, consider passing the `Random` into the method rather than creating it internally.  As it stands shuffling a structure repeatedly in a short span of time will result in the same shuffle taking place, which is...bad.

Answer (score 3):

> "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"

So put it in a non-generic static class...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // Fisher-Yates list-shuffle
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```